# React.js issues with re-rendering when trying to show notifications in a context from Apollo useQuery

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

So this is my what I am trying to do. I have created a global notifications context with a reducer to change the state.

My issue case now is, I am using Apollo hooks to do a query `useQuery` and when there is an error I want to show it in my global notifications.

So to do this, I need to dispatch to the reducer to show the notification, change the title and the message in the notification.

This triggers a state change on the global notification context which triggers a rerender which triggers the `useQuery` again. All this triggers an infinite rerender if you have an error response every time.

Does someone have a suggestion to have a global notifications system that could work for this?

The only solution I have left is to import the notification on every page where I need a notification.

Code:

```
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(NotificationsContext);
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USERS);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: 'ERROR',
        payload: {
          title: 'Query Error',
          subtitle: error.message,
        },
      });
    }

    if (!loading && data) {
      const newData = [];
      data.getUsers.users.forEach((user) => {
        const newUserRow = {};
        headers.forEach((header) => newUserRow[header] = user[header]);
        newData.push(newUserRow);
      });
      setRows(newData);
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using functional component and you can solve this by using `useQuery` inside the `useEffect` hook also do not forget to pass empty array as a 2nd argument of `useEffect`.

Hope this will solve your problem.

https://medium.com/@felippenardi/how-to-do-componentdidmount-with-react-hooks-553ba39d1571

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thank you very much for your input. Yes, I am using a functional component. I understand your solution and I have tried it before posting here.

The issue is then useEffect will only run once.

Apollo useQuery could give a few callbacks before the real answer is returned. So useEffect with blank array in the deps will not work. Because it needs to check for changes the whole time.

Comment: @GeorgSteyn I know you must have tried the useEffect thing by passing the 2nd parameter to it `[data]` so it will render every time whenever data changes.